# how do i combine php, WSDL, PHP?

Tags: php, c++, soap, wsdl

Im soooo like newbie to those things....what i have now..is soap and c++ program that out put a mobile phone number after user input a person's name. and wsdl file are also generated.

```
  { "John",     "123" },
  { "Michael",  "111" },
  { "Saras",     "324" },
  { "Grace",     "12312" },
```

now im trying to achieve this on a html, well first thing is try achieve this with php right?
say for example i hard coded php with input John and it will always display 123 whenever i open this php on a browser...is there any function that can directly bridge php and soap? or php with wsdl?  im a bit lost from here...need some inspiration :

c++ program has the function to get mobile phone number for example

```
   int test__getMobile(struct soap * soap, char * user, char ** mobile_num)
```

Comment: There is a manual section for the [SOAP functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) in PHP. Please use proper capitalizaton and avoid smileys in your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SOAP tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759987/php-soap-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports SOAP both for clients and for servers: http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

However, from the description, your problem is not clear. What's the role of the C++ code? Are you trying to implement a SOAP server in PHP that C++ code would consume?

Please edit the question rather than adding answers or comments. SO is not a forum.